# How create a NAO Virtual?

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How create a Virtual  NAO?

I'm interested in simulate to NAO, but get erros.

Install

http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-nao-robot
```

When use

```
roslaunch nao_bringup nao_sim.launch
```

Get this in the end:

```
ResourceNotFound: xacro
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_robot-devel
ROS path [2]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_robot
ROS path [3]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_gazebo_lastes
ROS path [4]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_gazebo_plugin
ROS path [5]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_extras
ROS path [6]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_description
ROS path [7]=/home/vincent/NAO/nao_common
ROS path [8]=/home/vincent/NAO/humanoid_msgs
ROS path [9]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [10]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

When continue with another tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/compileFromVirtualNao

Using

```
sudo bash -c 'echo app-portage/gentoolkit >> /etc/portage/package.keywords'
sudo bash -c 'echo dev-python/setuptools >> /etc/portage/package.keywords'
```

Get a similar error:
bash: /etc/portage/package.keywords: No existe el archivo o el directorio

A lot of thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191871/how-create-a-nao-virtual?/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Running nodes from a remote computer is different than compile from a virtual nao. To start I would suggest that you try to run your nodes remotely to get used to ROS and nao before doing more com)licated stuff.

the following ERROR:
ResourceNotFound: xacro
Means that your computer cannot find the ros package xacro : (rospack find xacro) this package should be in the following directory : /opt/ros/hydro/share/xacro.
If cou cannot find it : install it using sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-xacro

Compile from a Virtual nao is something totally different. Alderbaran provides a virtual machine that virtualize nao's hardware and OS. This way you can compile nodes to run directly on your nao and not on your computer.
On the gentoo virtual machine there is a folder /etc/portage. That kind of folder doesn't exist on a standard ubuntu desktop like the one your using. That's why it says that /etc/portage cannot be found.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2014-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0